# .M3U8 Video Streaming on Google TV

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-emulator, google-tv

I have used Vitamio library to play .M3U8 video format on Mobile(http://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/)

Could any one tell me the same would work on Google TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Vitamio uses native binary code (NDK) you will need to wait for the Jellybean release of Google TV before you will be able to use the library.